# How to use termfreq(field,value) for both the exact match and partial match in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I'm using solr5.3 in which i have column like **document** In which i will store the entire html page on it,
now i have application which search both the exact and partial search from that particular column in solr.
and also i'm calculating hits for it by using below formula

```
sum(0,termfreq(field,"{value}")
```

can i have regrx for the value column:

```
{value} for exact match
{value*} for partial match
```

I want the sum termfreq to caluclate both the exact match and partial match count.

Comment: You can't really; there is no support in `termfreq` for doing prefix matches. Depending on what you need the field for, using the terms component might be an option as it supports the `prefix` argument.